# Is hardware deinterlace possible?

Tags: video, opengles

Is there any idea how deinterlace would be applied using openmax components rendering into opengl?

---

EDIT: I'm still waiting my raspberry pi to arrive, so I couldn't test anything yet.

I've seen that GPU can achieve nice results with video playback, even at 1080p resolutions. Also, there is MPEG2 decoder which is very nice.

My question is about deinterlacing of MPEG2 streams from DVB which are interlaced on most terrestrial and satellite channels. If it would be done by CPU I don't think that results would be impressive at all. Could deinterlacing be done with shaders or is there any other viable method?

It would be too bad if r-pi couldn't deinterlace those videos, that could make it great home media center.

Comment: Hi there *10robinho*, welcome to *Raspberry Pi* Stack Exchange.  At the moment, this question is rather light on details. Could you add a little more information about what you are trying to achieve and what you have tried so far?

Comment: Thanks for nice words and suggestions. I've updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kodi, there are several deinterlacing methods to select from in the playback menu, which work very nicely when the hardware MPEG2 decoder is used (and not at all in software decoding, although the Pi 2 is fast enough otherwise).

I suggest you have a look at the source of Kodi (which uses omx-player) if you want to reproduce it in your own software.

Answer (score 0):

I would presume that the mpeg2 codec for the gpu can handle this.